# Access of Kubernetes Dashboard to view pod logs

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-dashboard

Is it good practics to allow access to the Kubernetes Dashboard access to developers to view the POD raw Logs directly from dashboard console. If yes with read-only access to the dashboard, then can anyone help me how to create a read-only user to access Kubernetes Dashboard? Currently, I can see there is one admin user with admin privilege is created upon deploying Kubernetes Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is a documentation on how to create a user with limited access. Go [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#use-case-1-create-user-with-limited-namespace-access)